# uDig Spatial ToolBox NetworkAttributeBuilder - strahler order

Tags: udig, strahler

I just upgraded my OsGeo4W, which upgraded uDig, I was hoping that would solve my issue with NetworkAttributeBuilder -stating it created stream order, but hung up of Pfafstratter..

Console output states:

```
Finished.
Calculate Strahler...
Finished.
Calculate Pfafstetter...
```

this would produce zero outputs - however, now that i have upgraded, I now have uDig 1.4.0b, and NetworkAttributeBuilder (& OmsNetworkAttributeBuilder) does not have Strahler as an output - i cannot find Strahler order in any of the Spatial Toolbox tools?  I have the same jgrasstools-0.7.7 Snapshot - i was running before I updated. OsGeo4W...

Anyone have similar issues?

In addition: I cannot get the Spatial Toolbox to run anything as I get a JDE - JDK error - the 'latest' uDig downloaded with OSGeo4W -app/uDig/ folders do not have the JDE folder as older versions did?

Answer (score 2):

The compatibility of JGrasstools with uDig can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/jgrasstools/wiki/JGrassTools4udig

If you download that linked library zip, it will be aligned with the 1.4.0b uDig.